# Listview jumps to the bottom on scrolling fast

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-listview

So as the title says , i have this problem with my listview . Im not using any ordinary listview , im using the observable scrollview library which is based on a listview .

Firstly, i would like to clarify a few things to give you guys more clarity.

1. I didn't have this problem until i changed a couple of things with my listview's custom adapters layout.
2. This seems wierd because i didn't get this problem before .
3. It scrolls at an abnormal rate , i just fling and it hits the bottom suddenly.
4. scrolling slowly doesn't cause the problem
5. Should i slow down my listview and try , if so how ?
6. I load more items on scroll , i have a footerview too and the footerview stays only a second or less .

Comment: Does it 'jerk' / 'freeze' before hitting the bottom ? Post the contents of your `getView()` method in your custom adapter. Also, [read this.](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/)

Comment: Yea it's like im in the 4th item and boom a small flash and 10th item.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9m718LXV getview.

Comment: Initially i thought it was because of notifyDataSetChanged() is triggered while scrolling so i commented out the add function.

Comment: Do you think currently its worth a switch to the all new recyclerview.

Comment: ViewHolder doesn't work when i implemented it , it gave me a null pointer on my text view , i did check that convertview was null etc... but no wonder what i declare its a null reference.

Answer (score 3):

This can also be caused by a bug in Android 5.1. [The bug report can be found here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159739). Two fast up swipes on a ListView cause it to hit the top of the list and then instantly scroll to the bottom.

Currently the only solution appears to be using a ScrollView instead of a ListView.

Comment: well this was on all android's so rule that out , and i don't use animators on lists which have dynamic items.

Answer (score 0):

In your `getView` method, you have

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);
```

Replace with

```
if (convertView == null) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);
}
```

And, it will be much better.

Btw, [ViewHolder is not so hard](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html). If this does not work, you *have* to implement ViewHolder correctly. Also avoid doing too much stuff in `getView` and make sure you load images asynchronously ( most imageLoader libraries will do this for you )

Comment: I did figure the problem out , it was becaue of calling notifydatasetchanged() on a dynamically inflated listview (more items loaded on scroll )